# Скрыть папку проекта C# .Net

Tags: c#

Всем привет!

Пишу проект на C# .Net 3.5 winforms, в этом проекте использую GeckoFx и в проекте есть папка "xulrunner" которая лежит рядом с программой.

Вопрос такой: как скрыть эту папку от пользователей? можно ли ее как то в exe'шник упаковать и от туда запускать?

p.s. про exe'шник это я конечно погорячился, но мало ли))

Comment: А зачем её скрывать от пользователей? Ваша программа инсталлируется в Program Files, юзер видит только ярлык. в 2017 году никто не запускает программы из-под командной строки.

Comment: @VladD я запускаю =) и пишу поддержку ключей командной строки для таких же ретроградов =). Но в целом вы скорее правы, пользователь, в среднем, уверен что удаляя ярлык с рабочего стола, он удаляет программу =(, так что можно особо не переживать о скрытии служебных папок, на крайний случай положить в AppData, там искать в последнюю очередь будут

Comment: @rdorn: Вы запускаете, да. Но вы программист. А пользователям давно уже всё равно. На некоторых системах вы как пользователь просто так и не получите доступ к файлам программы (например, на телефонах).

Comment: Про AppData тоже подумал, я думаю что это самый подходящий вариант. А вообще опасения мои далеко не в том что пользователь что то посмотрит или удалит из папки, это решаемо. Я просто пишу программу которая использует защиту от копирования и т.д. И я подумал "Если не добропорядочный пользователь(негодяй) увидит эту папку ему сразу станет понятно что это .Net и все мои хоть и не большие старания с .Net Reactor коту под хвост"

Comment: p.s. я знаю что gecko бывает не только под .Net и что проги ломаются на раз два, просто хоть как то запутать...

Comment: @rdorn, ну вот только appdata и не хватало. Чтоб в несколько раз больше места занять. Уже достали программы, которые в 3 профиля пихают по 2 гига неизвестно чего.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну не знаю, на домашних компах больше одного профиля бывает редко, а в корпоративной сети надо нормально перемещаемые профили настраивать, чтобы не забивалось место хламом. А так в целом лично меня наоборот больше устраивает, когда софт лежит именно там, как минимум потому что сама папка AppData не требует настройки особых прав для пользователя, у него там и так полные права

Comment: @rdorn, так они при одном кладут в трёх: сам пользователь, default user и all users. И объясни, нафига пользователю полные права на папку с xulrunner'ом - он его что, менять будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy программа запускается с правами пользователя, а ей может требоваться менять содержимое своих файлов, хотя бы для сохранения своих настроек. Вы же не предлагаете ради этого выдавать права локального администратора? а если нет, то придется давать права на папку или разбрасывать файлы программы по разным папкам, что для меня лично еще хуже, искать их чистить после удаления если инсталлятор не научили. А по поводу дефолтного и общего профилей, так это опять же камень в огород автора инсталлятора, а не самой идеи хранения в AppData

Comment: @rdorn, настройки обычно не весят 2 гига ;) А вот идея раскладывать неизменные файлы по профилям (вместо тех же program files) - плохая.

Comment: @Qwertiy про 2 гига не спорю, это маразм конечно, хотя случаи бывают разные, и на такой случай можно наковырять вполне валидный кейс, если заказчик программы совсем с головой не дружит.

Comment: @rdorn, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваши комментарии по *AppData* как ответ, так как вопрошающий [написал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624209/208074) следующее: `Спасибо за ответы! Вариант с AppData самый подходящий. Буду его использовать.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простейшем случае, можно установить у папки атрибут Hidden, по-умолчанию отображение скрытых файлов и папок отключено.

Для служебных файлов программ есть папка AppData. Папка является скрытой по-умолчанию, но пользователь имеет в ней полные права, поэтому никаких дополнительных манипуляций по настройке прав пользователя не потребуется. Этих папок, вообще говоря, минимум две, персональная для пользователя и общая для всех пользователей, что как бы позволяет делать различные варианты установки персональную или общую, хотя в случае установки программы для всех пользователей, я бы рекомендовал классический вариант размещения в ProgrammFiles с использованием не менее классических инсталяторов.

Есть много разных мнений на счет использования этой папки, в комментариях уже обсудили два из них, повторять не вижу смысла. Если программе не требуются особые права в системе и соответствующий инсталятор, то в контексте .NET и VisualStudio можно воспользоваться технологией ClickOnce. Инсталятор разместит вашу опубликованную программу в AppData пользователя и, при соответствующей настройке, даже будет автоматически проверять наличие обновлений, если вы собираетесь их выпускать разумеется, при этом не требуя от пользователя обладать правами администратора системы для установки и обновления программы.

По поводу скрытия служебных папок - не вижу смысла особенно по этому поводу переживать, т.к. средний уровень компьютерной грамотности пользователя довольно низкий, то лазить по служебным папкам просто так ни кто не станет, пока "добрый человек" не выложит подробное видео "как хакнуть программу X" (поменяйте заголовок на свой вкус, и да, именно видео, статьи уже не то, этож читать надо,  да и писать в общем то тоже), а это произойдет, только когда (и если) ваша программа станет достаточно популярной для обычного пользователя.

Видеть такое очень печально, но вероятность изменения в лучшую сторону со временем только уменьшается, так что **security through obscurity** - решение идеологически неправильное, но часто является необходимым и достаточным.

Answer (score 1):

Буду использовать вариант с AppData, это самый подходящий вариант.